# Meaning of "fringewards"

Tags: meaning

In [a trailer for a DLC for the videogame Stellaris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBL9dTwVi4I&ab_channel=ParadoxInteractive), the word *fringewards* is mentioned in a sea shanty song:

> And it's windy weather,
> boys, stormy weather!
> When the wind blows, then
> we are all together!
> Blow ye winds fringewards,
> Blow ye winds blow!

I googled it a lot but could not find a meaning that makes sense in the context of the song.

What would be the meaning of this word in this context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The context here is that in the game, some planets are designated as "fringe planets":

> This planet is sparsely populated world on the fringes of the collective

[image: game screenshot showing the fringe planet description]

Screenshot from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellaris/comments/u1dc4c/just_discovered_this_no_wonder_my_economy_sucks/)

*Fringewards* uses the [productive suffix -wards](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/english-usage/what-is-the-difference-between-ward-and-wards#:%7E:text=%2Dwards%20is%20a%20suffix%20that,or%20look%20towards%20the%20north.) (the same suffix in words like "westwards") to mean "in the direction of the fringe (of the collective)".

Real shanties have lines like "[blow ye winds westerly](http://www.stephengriffith.com/folksongindex/the-fish-of-the-sea-blow-ye-winds-westerly/)" because a boat that's trying to travel east needs a wind blowing from the west in order to effectively use its sails.

Answer (score 4):

It means 'toward(s) the fringe', whatever and wherever the *fringe* is located, metaphorically.
You can do that with any locational expression; *-ward*'s been around since Old English.

From the OED:

***-ward***, suffix, OE. -*weard*, primarily forming adjectives with the sense `having a specified direction'

> ... followed by many more lines of etymology (including the fact that it's cognate with the English word *worth*), and legions of special compounds (like *untoward* meaning 'improper'), leading to its productive modern suffixal use:

8. Examples of nonce-words (advs.) f. sb. or proper name (rarely pron.) + *-ward:*

- 1623 L. Andrewes Serm. i. xvi. (1629) 154 *In Man, there was onward* [= *oneward*] *an abridgement of all the rest. Gather God and him into one, and so you have all.*
- 1728 Swift Let. to Pope 26 July  *You are the most temperate man Godward, and the most intemperate yourselfward of most I have known.*
- 1752 H. Walpole Let. to Mann 27 July, *Our beauties are travelling Paris-ward.*
- 1793 Cowper Let. to Lady Hesketh 29 Aug. *I will therefore .. refer the time of your journey Weston-ward entirely to your own election.*
- 1849 Poe Marginalia Wks. 1864 III. 499 *The whole tendency of the age is Magazine-ward.*
- 1851 Carlyle Sterling ii. iii *In the afternoon we went on the Thames Putney-ward together.*
- 1865 E. Burritt Walk to Land's End 241 *The waif breezes .. convey but a little way youward the breath of thyme they take up from these rough hills and valleys.*
- 1893 Tablet 4 Nov. 742 *Its eyes turned eastward and past-ward.*
- 1899 G. F. Monkshood Kipling 69 *Mr. Kipling thoughtfully points out to him that men do not float Simla-ward in paper ships upon a stream of ink.*

Comment: Google NGrams confirms my suspicion that there's a pretty clear US/UK usage split between AmE [***-ward***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=move+upwards%2Cmove+upward&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) and BrE [***wards***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=move+upwards%2Cmove+upward&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3). But on a whim I searched for ***pubwards*** - which I doubt I've ever actually heard before, but it's obvious many of my fellow countrymen do indeed like to head pubwards of an evening!

Comment: I use _-wards_ at least as much as the non-essy variety (the -s ain't a plural, whatever it is).  [There are a few minor differences, though](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/besides.html).

Comment: I already knew before checking for a possible US/UK usage split that I personally don't really distinguish between ***toward / towards*** in any contexts I can think of. But until I followed your link, I had no idea that I'm quite likely to "under-articulate" or completely discard the **/w/** in casual speech, regardless of whether I end with **/z/** or not. By the same token, I doubt I'd notice if other people didn't articulate the **/w/** (I "expect" it, so I assume I heard it even if I *didn't*). I find it interesting that /z/ after **beside** (always?) denotes the ***metaphoric*** usage.